# R crashes with sf library

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp

Occasionally, R crashes when I try to load `sf` library. When there is no chrash, it is not possible to convert a `sp` SpatialPolygonDataFrame object from `sp` into `sf` ()

```
x_sf = st_as_sf(x)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: What does "Not possible" mean? Do you get an error? What error? Do you get any messages when you start R or do `library(sf)`? What version of everything are you on? Problems like this must be down to something in your system so we can only help if you give details of your system, except for the usual suggestions of "re-install everything?"

Comment: `sf` will report versions for `gdal`, `geos`, `proj` upon library(sf) executing without error. `packageVersion(sf or sp), will then give you those. As there has been substantial development in the spatial pkgs, and discussion of the impacts of the changes, visit GitHub.com/r-spatial/sf for install at bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your time! "not possible" = R crashes, no error, just keep on working and it is not possible even to save or close R.
There is no message when I start R or `library(sf)`.
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18). 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit).
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042).
sf version 1.0-1.
sp version 1.4-5. installed with all dependencies.

Comment: Solved!
I re-installed everything.
Thanks!